# How to format json parameters in HTTP request?

Tags: json, http, curl, post

My application retrieves an authentication token from a remote server. The following request works fine, but I'd like to read the parameters from a json file:

```
curl -X POST "https://identity-r.my_office.ch/realms/bfs-sis-r/protocol/openid-connect/token" 
-H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d "username=dataproducer&password=dataproducer&grant_type=password&client_id=BFS.SIS&scope=openid profile roles email"
```

I created this json file to store the parameters:

```
credentials.json

{"username": "dataproducer", 
"password": "dataproducer", 
"grant_type": "password", 
"client_id": "BFS.SIS", 
"scope": "openid profile roles email"
}
```

and I try to use it in the request:

```
curl -X POST "https://identity-r.my_office.ch/realms/bfs-sis-r/protocol/openid-connect/token" 
-H "accept: */*" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d @credentials.json
```

But the response is

> {"error":"RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type"}

Can you help me to format this request correctly?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the server even accepts JSON as posted data?

Comment: Yes it does. But it looks like the json I send contains escape characters like \" instead of simply " around data, which causes the error. I can test it with Swagger ...

Comment: There are no escaped double-quotes in the _'credentials.json'_ you showed above, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this code:

```
curl -H "Accept: */*" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST --data "@path_of_file" https://identity-r.my_office.ch/realms/bfs-sis-r/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Or send -H with charset:

```
curl -H "Accept: */*" -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -X POST --data "@path_of_file" https://identity-r.my_office.ch/realms/bfs-sis-r/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Also you can change and try `--data` to `--data-binary`. The difference is `--data` will cause curl to strip newlines, but `--data-binary` won't.

Comment: Unfortunately, all this has no effect :(